# Build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift

Tags: swift, git, github, cocoapods

For the first time I want to create my own pod. I am following this tutorial:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-cocoapod--cms-24332

At step 7 (Making Your Pod Available), step 2, I am having problem validating my .podspec file. I get this error:

> The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set
>   to a supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can be
>   set in the build settings editor.

I have updated cocoapods to the newest version and I want to use Swift 4.1. I did set Swift 4.1 as compiler settings for the pod file, and my main project file.

The project is here: https://github.com/Jasperav/TemplatePrivateRepo

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: I guess you must specify swift version when linting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work when opening the .swift-version file and only set '4.1' as content (without the '')